# haproxy source ip address shows Kubernetes node ip address

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy, filebeat

I have HAproxy running in a Kubernetes container. This is what a sample log looks like

```
<134>Jul 20 13:11:37 haproxy[6]: <SOURCE_ADDRESS> [20/Jul/2020:13:11:37.713] front gameApi/game-api-test 0/0/0/9/9 200 384 - - ---- 37/37/0/0/0 0/0 {<FORWARD_FOR_ADDRESS>} "GET /api/games/lists?dtype=brandlist HTTP/1.1"
```

The <SOURCE_ADDRESS> here is the haproxy kubernetes node ip address and i need it to be the clinet/forwardfor ip address so that filebeat is able to parse the geolocation correctly.

Edit:

I found a solution using haproxy which is to simply set `http-request set-src hdr(x-forwarded-for)`

However attempting to use the solution `externalTrafficPolicy: Local` seems to break my haproxies ability to serve website. When i try to reach a website it would say "this site can't be reached" or "Secure Connection Failed"

**haproxy service**

```
apiVersion: v1

kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: haproxy-test
  labels:
    app: haproxy-test
  namespace: test
  annotations:
    # Note that the backend talks over HTTP.
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-sload-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:us-east-2:redacted:certificate/redacted
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "https"
spec: 
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports: 
  - port: 80
    name: http
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: "TCP"
  - port: 443
    name: https
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: "TCP"
  selector: 
    app: haproxy-test
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: haproxy-test
  namespace: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: haproxy-test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: haproxy-test
        image: <redacted>.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/haproxy:$TAG
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "50m"
          requests:
            cpu: "25m"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can preserve source IP by setting `externalTrafficPolicy` to `local`. Check this question for more details [How do Kubernetes NodePort services with Service.spec.externalTrafficPolicy=Local route traffic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60067188/how-do-kubernetes-nodeport-services-with-service-spec-externaltrafficpolicy-loca)

Alternatively use `http-request set-src hdr(x-forwarded-for)` to configure HAProxy to use the contents of the `X-Forward-For` header to establish its internal concept of the source address of the request, instead of the actual IP address initiating the inbound connection.

Comment: Before seeing this answer i found an alternative solution which was to set `  http-request set-src hdr(x-forwarded-for)` in my ha proxy config

Comment: I have edited my answer to add this alternative for future readers